# How to get feedback from js websocket - be sure that message was received

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, esp32

I am working on an application with esp32 and web server. Basically when I open a page, I send a message using websocket to esp32 and then execute some functions. My issue is that randomly, esp32 doesn t get the message from the websocket and I need to refresh page few times till it get it. Sometimes works first time sometimes i need to do refresh 4 or 5,6 times till esp32 get the message.
Initially I had js code in separate js file but now I included it in the html page. There was no change in the behaviour.

This is my js code:

```
<script>
var ident = "";
var proto = "...";

var gateway = `ws://${window.location.hostname}/ws`;
var websocket;

 window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
 console.log(gateway);
  function initWebSocket() {
    websocket = new WebSocket(gateway);
    websocket.onopen    = onOpen;
    websocket.onclose   = onClose;
    websocket.onmessage = onMessage; // <-- add this line
  }
  function onOpen(event) {
    websocket.send('connect_ask_function1');
    console.log("connect_ask_function1");
  }
  function onClose(event) {
    setTimeout(initWebSocket, 2000);
  }
  
  function onMessage(event) {
    var values = event.data.split("|");

    console.log("event data");
    console.log(event.data);
    
    ident = values[0];
    if (ident === "results"){
        proto = values[1];
    }
    else if (ident === "please_wait"){
        proto = "...";

    }
        
    proto = proto.replace( /[\r\n]+/gm, "" );
    
    document.getElementById("proto").innerText = proto;
    
}
function onLoad(event) {
    initWebSocket();
}
</script>
```

On esp32 I am using ESPAsyncWebServer.h and AsyncWebSocket

```
void handleWebSocketMessage(void *arg, uint8_t * data, size_t len) {
  String str = (char*)data;
  if (str.substring(0, 1) == "r"){
    data_send = str.substring(1, 5);
      RPM = data_send.substring(0, 4).toInt();
      data_send1 = "<" + String(RPM) + ">";
      Serial.println(data_send1);
  }
 else if (str.substring(0, 1) == "t"){
    data_send = str.substring(1, 3);
   TMP = data_send.toInt();
    set_temp(TMP);
  }
  else if ( str == "ask_index") {/////
    OBD_MODE = 0;
  }
  else if ( str == "connect_ask_function1") {
    OBD_MODE = 1;
    OBD_DTC_READ = 1;
    ws.textAll("please_wait");
  }
```

When I open the page I send to esp32 "connect_ask_function1". Esp32 reply to me with "please_wait" and then start executing a function. When is ready send the results.
Once esp32 get "connect_ask_function1" always I get the results, so my guess is that something prevent esp32 to get the first "connect_ask_function1"...

Any idea of how I can fix this?

Thank you very much